# How to connect XMPP server through XMPPFramework in ios in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I am connecting to XMPP server through XMPPFramework in IOS in objective C,
I had initialized the connection  parameter in viewDidLoad method like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
xmppStream = [[XMPPStream alloc] init];
[xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

xmppStream.hostName = @"hostname";
xmppStream.hostPort = 5222;

NSString *username = @"name@domainname.net";
NSString *password = @"123456";

[xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:username]];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![xmppStream oldSchoolSecureConnectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't connect to server %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
}
```

And Trying to Authenticate in on button click like this:

```
- (IBAction)connectToXmpp:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"%hhd", [xmppStream isConnected]);
NSError *error = nil;

if (![xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:@"123456" error:&error]) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Can't authenticate %@", [error localizedDescription]]
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
}
[xmppStream sendElement:[XMPPPresence presence]];
}
```

But getting Error message on button click here is the error message:

[image]

Can some one please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Have you got your solution ?

Comment: @Ankit Agarwal yes i got it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@prem nath

In Above code you are trying to connect to server in `- (void)viewDidLoad`.
But You can authenticate with password after server connection established.

So `- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender` of `XMPPStream Delegate` is called when connection is established. You have to authenticate with server in XMPPStream Delegate.